# about Speed: Python VS Java

Tags: java, python

Just curious about speed of Python and Java..
Intuitively, Python should be much slower than java, but I want to know more...Could anybody give me more? or introduce some nice post to read?

Comment: http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/python.php

Comment: What exactly is your reason for caring?

Comment: Speed only matters for the specific application you have in mind.  Please post the code you want to compare in Python and in Java.  Then, as part of posting the code you want to compare, please post the run times for that code.  Then we can tell you which is faster.

Comment: I think it is a fair question to ask for results 'in general' -- one does not always start with specific use case in mind, but wants to know typical cases. Not everyone has same narrow scope of solving one concrete problem at a time; others like learning in advance.

Comment: @StaxMan: Since a bad choice of algorithm can make "in general" comparisons utterly invalid, I'm not sure they're helpful.  How would you compare a Python list comprehension against a Java implementation that had to be built from scratch?  I don't see how "in general" can be valid when there are so many special cases and features.

Comment: @S.Lott >> Please post the code you want to compare ... please post the run times for that code. Then we can tell you which is faster. << Please don't be so obstructive and unhelpful. Plainly Andy Leman was curious to see whatever examples other people had to show.

Comment: @S.Lott >> I don't see how "in general" can be valid when there are so many special cases and features. << Do you see how statistics can be valid?

Comment: @igouy: "Do you see how statistics can be valid?" That's my point.  When Python has a special-case construct with special optimization, how is that a statistically relevant comparison against Java which lacks that specific feature?

Comment: @S.Lott - Apparently you don't see how statistics can be valid.  http://books.google.com/books?id=HOPyiNb9UqwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @igouy: Sadly, I can't figure out why you keep repeat that phrase.  I use statistics daily (I work with actuaries).  I don't see how odd special cases of weird programming language constructs can be compared.  If you could explain that, I'd be better informed and could learn something.

Comment: @S.Lott - Do you see how each individual person is a special (sometimes wierd) case, and yet actuaries can make valid statements about "people"?

Comment: @igouy: Actually, I don't see that.  They make measurements of classes of people who have similar attributes.  They often refuse to handle weird special cases (dying of three terminal diseases at the same time).  Similarly, they rarely make "in general" statements because they are careful to assure that it is an "apples-to-apples" comparisons of things with identical attributes.  So, I'm really lost with how programming languages can be compared in general.  I'm hoping for an explanation.

Comment: @S.Lott - Are they being asked to make valid statements about "people"?

Comment: @igouy: they rarely make "in general" statements about "people" because they are careful to assure that it is an "apples-to-apples" comparisons of people with measurably identical attributes.  I can't see how any Java code can be compared against a Python generator function.  They're too different to invite an "in general" comparison.  I'm hoping you can provide some actual education on how two different languages can be compared.

Comment: @S.Lott - Are you saying they would be unable to answer a general question?

Comment: @igouy: I'm not sure what you're aiming at.  I don't see how questions about actuaries will help me understand what an "in general" comparison can possibly mean between Java and Python.  I'm hoping for some definition or specific example of an "in general" comparison between programming languages which are fundamentally different.

Comment: @S.Lott - You seemed to suggest that you were familiar with statistics because you work with acturaries. Do you see how this acturial table makes valid "in general" about the US population, even though the individuals in the US population have widely dis-similar attributes? http://www.ssa.gov/OACT/STATS/table4c6.html

Comment: @igouy: How does that apply to two utterly different programming languages? A large population of people is not the same as comparing two languages.  I can't see how there's a "statistical basis" for comparing two things which have almost no common attributes.  Rather than give examples of general statistics, please explain how to compare two programming languages "in general".  Please define "in general" in some way that this question can be answered.

Comment: @S.Lott - Please acknowledge (yes/no) that you either do or do not see how the acturial table makes valid "in general" statements, so we can move the discussion along.

Comment: @igouy: An actuarial table makes statements about sub-populations with identical attributes.  It doesn't make vague, imprecise "in general" claims.  It makes narrowly defined claims about men, smokers, previous cancer patients.  How does that map to the vague, undefined "in general" attached to this question?  Java "in general" means ANY java code, including very poorly written.  Python "in general" means ANY python code, no matter how much it exploits unique features of Python.  What does "in general" mean except "all possible" code?  Even code that can't be compared.

Comment: @S.Lott - I posted a specific example of an actuarial table and asked you specifically about that example. The only "identical attributes" shown in that table are Exact Age and Gender (the "Social Security area population" is too vague for your notion of "identical attribute"). You are plainly wrong to suggest that actuarial table makes narrowly defined claims about "smokers, previous cancer patients".

Comment: @igouy: Thanks for helping me understand "in general" with programming language comparison.  You've done a good job of clarifying how Java's odd and unique features can be compared with Python's odd and unique features in a general way.  The lack of overlap between the languages is cleverly handled through statistics.  Your clear definition of "in general" was helpful.

Comment: @S.Lott - 'Twas New Year and the stench of sarcasm filled the air. Even when presented with a specific example you've refused to acknowledge that example makes valid "in general" statements, and you've provided no reason why you think that specific example does not make valid "in general" statements. As you refuse to acknowledge the facts that have been put before you so far, the discussion is stuck at - "apparently you don't see how statistics can be valid".

Comment: @igouy: I'm trying to understand programming "in general".  I don't care much about actuarial in general.  I want to understand programming in general.  Please simply define this "in general" concept without resorting to elaborate reasoning by analogy.  Analogies are largely useless here, because the programming language population is 2 and I can't see how statistics work with only 2 entities.  Please simply provide the necessary instruction/definition/rules so I can understand what you're talking about without debating my level of understanding of actuarial tables.  Just define it, please.

Comment: @igouy: If an actuarial table makes valid "in general" statements, what does that have to do with Java and Python?  Please provide some definition for "in general" that can help me.  If it helps you, pretend that I fully understand how actuarial tables make in general statements.  Move on.  Please.

Comment: @S.Lott - There should be no need for anyone to guess what you understand when you take a straightforward role in a conversation. Please acknowledge (yes/no) that you either do or do not see how that actuarial table makes valid "in general" statements, so we can move the discussion along.

Comment: @igouy:  [This seems totally silly.]  Yes.  I totally see how that actuarial table makes valid "in general" statements.  Please move on.  I totally see it.  How does a summary of multiple data points possibly apply to a universe of 2 data points, both of which are programming languages with few common features?  Please define "in general" as it applies to programming language performance.

Comment: @S.Lott - [Totally silly not to have answered straightaway.] Your very first comment talked about "the code you want to compare in Python and in Java" - the universe of Python code and Java code has more than 2 data points.

Comment: @igouy: [This seems totally silly to demand weird concessions.] How is it possible to compare this universe of code?  I have Python code is a bad example of Python.  I have Python code that includes constructs not available in Java.  How do I measure Python and Java "in general" when the code is not comparable in any way that I can see?  Please define "in general" in some way that I can compare these two languages.

Comment: @S.Lott - [This established your agreement that there can be valid "in general" statements.] How is it possible to compare the Social Security area population universe of people? It has people who smoke. It has people with 20/20 vision and people blind from birth. And yet you - 'totally see how that actuarial table makes valid "in general" statements' - and so you also must already understand "in general" in some way. (Again, from your very first comment you talked about "the code you want to compare in Python and Java" rather than "compare these two languages".)

Comment: @igouy: Please drop the reasoning by analogy.  Please.  It's too complex.  Please just define "in general" comparison between Java and Python.  Please just provide me a working definition of how I do "in general" comparison between two languages.  Please.  I can't reason by analogy like this.  I need a definition.  Please provide a procedure or definition or something so that I can conduct my own "in general" comparisons between Java and Python.  I need a way to get the numbers.  Not a complex mental model but a finite, definite and effective process for comparison.  Please.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/general_1#general_1__3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current standard implementation of Python (CPython) is slower than Java because the standard CPython implementation doesn't have a powerful [JIT compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation). Yet.

There have been several projects with the aim of producing a faster implement of Python:

- [Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/)
- [Unladen Swallow](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/wiki/ProjectPlan)
- [PyPy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/)

From what I've tried some of these projects can give very good speed ups for specific algorithms, but you still won't get it to run as fast as Java for typical application code. Most of the current effort seems now to be directed towards PyPy.

Comment: Or rather, a universal JITer. It has Psyco, which only runs on IA32 systems.

Comment: There are implementations of python that include a JIT compiler. http://psyco.sourceforge.net/ and http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/ come to mind.

Comment: Be careful of conflating Python -- the language -- with a specific implementation of Python.  A Py2Exe implementation might be considerably faster than a CPython implementation.

Comment: recently released PyPy 1.5 is much faster than CPython, in 6 of the benchmarks on http://speed.pypy.org it is more than 10x faster. It would be great to see some latest PyPy vs Java speed comparison.

Answer (score 11):

The lack of a JIT mentioned is one reason, but another reason is that Python is dynamic. Yes, that does make the language slower. You can see for yourself by using Cython.

A function written in Python can often be compiled to C with Cython. It makes it faster. But it get's really fast when you start adding type information to the variables and parameters, as both Cython and the C-compiler can start applying various simple optimizations that you can't do when the types are dynamic.

So one part of the difference is the inherent dynamicism of Python.

On the future: Python 3 has function annotations: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/ I expect that in a couple of years time, the JIT compilers like PyPy and UnladenSwallow will use this information, and you'll see Python being just as fast as Java, and with some careful applying of Cython, even faster. :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have data points to give, but one interesting aspect is that there are Python implementations on JVM (ditto for many other dynamic/scripting languages) -- JPython and [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) for example. This could allow some Python applications to run at speeds comparable to native Java applications, assuming implementation of Python runtime itself (on JVM) is efficient.

Answer (score 1):

There are many great answers here as to why Java is faster than Python, 2 of the most common answers are that Python is dynamically typed, and that Java has several extremely powerful Just-in Time Compilers (2 Production quality, several experimental and not for general use) in it's arsenal, with only the C# Common Language Runtime capable of matching it. This is true, but even so, there is one last reason as to why Java is still faster, and oddly enough, it has to do with differences in how Java's Interpreter is designed, vs Python's Interpreter.

Right now, this is the source code of the Interpreter in production for the OpenJDK/HotSpot JVM, Java's reference implementation (There is actually another legacy Interpreter in the JVM source code which was the old one written by James Gosling himself way back when Java was first created, but that one is outdated and not compiled into the actual binary unless you compile it from source with special flags for debugging purposes. Interestingly enough, this is the interpreter responsible for earning Java the reputation of being horrendously slow back in those days):
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/interpreter/templateInterpreter.cpp

This, in contrast, is the code segment of the CPython interpreter that executes Python opcode:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L1847

Notice something different between the 2?

While CPython has a massive for loop with a switch case for every single opcode possible (This is true for almost every other interpreter out there actually, other than Java), there is not a single loop, if else, or switch case in Java's Interpreter. Why is this?

The answer is that Java's Interpreter is a special type called a Template Interpreter, which to date is the only one of it's kind. Unlike most designs, instead of a switch case to evaluate Java bytecode, Java's Interpreter has a big arraylist of bytecode, mapped to native machine language when the application is started. This way, the Java Interpreter doesn't need to evaluate bytecode at all, it just inserts the bytecode as an array index, loads native machine language, and directly runs it on the CPU. This means Java's "Interpreter" is actually a discount Compiler, since it runs your code directly on the hardware. CPython on the other hand, like many other interpreters today, is a run of the mill bytecode interpreter, which processes python opcode in software. This obviously makes Python slower to run than Java, even without JIT.

As to why Java has such a unique Interpreter design not used anywhere else, it's because it needs to run interpreted code directly with JIT Compiled code seamlessly, and the ingenious design of having the Interpreter contain a table with bytecode->machine language pairs rather that directly execute it in software was the best way to achieve this goal.